# How do I fix the 'Cannot send messages to this user' DiscordAPIError?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm having an issue with sending a private message on the `guildMemberAdd` event.

Here is the code:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.send('Welcome to the server.');
});
```

This causes this error:

```
(node:11760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\AckeeXZ\Desktop\BOT\californianetwork\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\AckeeXZ\Desktop\BOT\californianetwork\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11760) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely thrown because the member has their DM's closed, which means the bot cannot send any messages to them.

Users can disallow direct messages from server members in the "Privacy & safety" settings.

[image]

There is no other way to bypass this, but you can handle the error using `.catch()` or a `try - catch` block.

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.send('Welcome to the server.').catch(e => console.log(e));
});

// or 

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    try { 
        await member.send('Welcome to the server.'); 
    } catch(e) { 
        console.log(e); 
    }
});
```